# How to tell the needed doping element for semiconductors?

Tags: electrons, electronic-configuration, semiconductors

I was reading about a crystal that is a semiconductor, galena. I am confused on how to tell what elements are needed to dope it to make a p or n type semiconductor, as well as how to know which elements to use for doping other semiconductors.

Comment: A priori, you might have a really hard time. One would need to look at it experimentally, or perhaps with modeling like density functional theory (DFT). While you are, perhaps, lulled into a false sense of security through thinking you understand silicon, remember that even there boron is a great dopant while nitrogen is  absolutely not. And don't try to compare silicon with, say, diamond...